# jQuery dynamic offset

Tags: jquery, variables, dynamic, accordion, offset

So i have been working on this http://jsfiddle.net/Hiilo/hCVf4/

What i would like to achieve is that the offset of  #offy would be equal to the accordion height, but i just can't figure out how to update the offset.top value.

This here manages to give the correct value on page load but wont be updated if i click on the accordion header.

```
var offset= function() {
    var offsetValue = $("#accordion").height();
    return offsetValue;
     };
```

Now if I look in to the console it seems to be updated

```
    $(".ui-accordion-header").click(function(){
    console.log(offset());
});
```

I have tried to set the variable offset inside the click function but then I cant get the updated value outside the function.
Now i know that this has everything to do with variable scope and closure(been reading up about them) but i'm still left in the dark.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are looing for this: http://jsfiddle.net/hCVf4/13/

1. Change the handler from header click to the change callback, because on click accordion still not finished animation and height will be invalid:

   ```
   change: function(event, ui) { updaterOffcet(); }
   ```
2. Change the style of the block to the `position:absolute; left:300px;`
3. Set the `css(top:myTopValue)` on the callback

Comment: Is this answer to your question? ;)